# rails ignores my redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes

Rails is ignoring my redirect.

Use Case:

1. user navigates to his account and selects the option to display his subscription status
2. app lists his current subscription and the option to cancel it
3. user cancels the subscription
4. app updates the subscription record and *should* redirect the user back to the subscriptions action

   -> but rails ignores this last step... any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Routes

```
map.resources :users, ..., :member => { ..., :subscriptions => :get, :subscribe => :post, :unsubscribe => :put}
```

Controllers:

```
  def subscriptions
    @tradesman = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @subscription = @tradesman.current_subscription || Subscription.new
    @all_subscriptions = Subscription.find(:all)
  end

  def subscribe
    @tradesman = User.find_by_id(params[:id])    
    @subscription = current_user.subscriptions.build(params[:subscription])
    @subscription.update_attributes(:started_at => Time.zone.now)
    @subscription.save
    redirect_to :action => 'subscriptions', :id => @tradesman.id
  end

  def unsubscribe
    @tradesman = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @subscription = @tradesman.current_subscription
    @subscription.update_attributes(:ended_at => Time.zone.now)
    @subscription.save
    redirect_to :action => 'subscriptions', :id => @tradesman.id
  end
```

View:

```
<div class = 'wrapper'>
  <%= render :partial => "my_account_leftbar" %>
  <% form_for @subscription, :url => subscribe_user_path(current_user) do |f| %>

        <% @all_subscriptions.each do |subscription| %>
      <div class="field">Start: <%= subscription.started_at %></div><br><br>
        <% end %>

        <% if @subscription.new_record? %>
      <div class="field">
            <%= f.check_box :subscription_type %>
            <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit "Subscribe", :class => "button mr8" %>
          </div>
      </div>
        <% else -%>     
        <%= f.check_box :subscription_type, :value => @subscription.subscription_type, :disabled => true %>

            <% form_for @subscription, :url => unsubscribe_user_path(current_user) do |f| %>
          <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit "Unsubscribe", :class => "button mr8" %>
          </div>
            <% end %>

        <% end %>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Found the bug in the view where I nested the 'unsubscribe' form within the 'subscribe' form - what didn't make sense. I rearranged my view (separated those two forms, one in the 'if' part and the other in the 'else' part. Works fine now.

Comment: Will post the new view as soon as stackoverflows allows it..

Answer (score 0):

Use `redirect_to` instead of `render` (last method call in your `unsubscribe` action).

Comment: Thanks for your input. Sorry, I actually tried redirect_to (and it didn't work). I also tried previously render (which doesn't work either) but forgot to replace it. So: redirect_to doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Found the bug in the view where I nested the 'unsubscribe' form within the 'subscribe' form - what didn't make sense.

I rearranged my view (separated those two forms, one in the 'if' part and the other in the 'else' part. Works fine now:

```
<div class = 'wrapper'>
  <%= render :partial => "my_account_leftbar" %>
  <% @all_subscriptions.each do |subscription| %>
    <div class="field">Start: <%= subscription.started_at %></div><br><br>
  <% end %>

    <% if @subscription.new_record? %>
    <% form_for @subscription, :url => subscribe_user_path(current_user) do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
            <%= f.check_box :subscription_type %>
            <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit "Subscribe", :class => "button mr8" %>
          </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <% else -%>
    <% form_for @subscription, :url => unsubscribe_user_path(current_user) do |f| %>
    <%= f.check_box :subscription_type, :value => @subscription.subscription_type, :disabled => true %>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Unsubscribe", :class => "button mr8" %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```